# Event binding for an event name containing a colon in Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, event-binding

Is it possible to bind to an event in Angular where the event name contains a colon, e.g. `Foo:event`?

`<div (Foo:event)="onFooEvent()"></div>`

gives error "Unsupported event target null for event activated."

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm using a library of ES6 classes that generate events with that naming style and I need to listen for said events.  I can use addEventListener to accomplish this.  I was just wondering if there was a way to do it through event binding instead.

Comment: We don't know what `onFooEvent` looks like, but if it expects an `event` argument, you can try `(Foo:event)="onFooEvent($event)"`.